# Showing API response on webpage

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am able to console.log() the response of API call in json format on my node console, how can I get it to display the result to my webpage, with styling.

Basically in app.post()  I have made the console.log() after making the request.
I am getting the response, but I need to display it on my webpage.

```
app.post("/",function(req,res){

            // INSTANTIATE A CLIENT
    let credentials= new CognitiveServicesCredentials('API-key-goes-here');
    let client=new WebSearchAPIClient(credentials);

            // MAKE REQUEST AND PRINT RESULT
    const query=req.body.item;
    client.web.search(query).then((result) => {
        let properties = ["images", "webPages", "news", "videos"];
        for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
            if (result[properties[i]]) {
                // console.log(result);    // To see result types and all.
                // console.log(result[properties[i]]); // To see all tyes of results.
                // console.log(result.videos); // To display only the video results. 
                // res.send(result[properties[i]].value);
                // let url=(result[properties[i]].value);
                // console.log(url); // gives the same result.  

            } else {
                console.log(`No ${properties[i]} data`);
            }
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        throw err;
    })
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your response object set type, JSON parse and send.

`res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));`

Comment: Could you please see it and tell me what to do?

Comment: after setting header you can pass your object directly